# Android App Emulator Issue

Tags: java, android, android-activity, mobile

I have created a project in Android Studio:
package com.example.apps.newapplication;
Java code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout DakotasLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        Button redButton = new Button(this);

        DakotasLayout.addView(redButton);
        setContentView(DakotasLayout);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app.newapplication">

    <application>
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem is my app shuts down every time I launch it in the emulator.
I'm not sure what's wrong in my java file. It might be my manifest file that's wrong, but I'm not sure.
Here's the logcat:

```
Error Logs:
01-13 18:24:51.244 4486-4486/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-13 18:24:51.328 4486-4494/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
01-13 18:24:51.369 4486-4494/? W/art: Suspending all threads took: 41.636ms
01-13 18:24:51.373 4486-4486/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.apps.newapplication-2/lib/x86
01-13 18:24:51.423 4486-4486/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-13 18:24:51.424 4486-4486/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.apps.newapplication, PID: 4486
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.apps.newapplication/com.example.apps.newapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:98)
at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:91)
at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:73)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:205)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
at com.example.apps.newapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-13 18:25:03.649 4486-4494/com.example.apps.newapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 60.192ms
01-13 18:25:22.653 4486-4494/com.example.apps.newapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 44.409ms
01-13 18:25:29.152 4486-4494/com.example.apps.newapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 24.137ms
```

Comment: Can you post what is output to logcat?

Comment: Actually your error is probably a `NullPointerException`. You are using `findViewById(...)` but are calling `setContentView()` on a `RelativeLayout`. Usually that is called referencing an xml layout file.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Posted Logcat

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan What exactly do I need to change?

Comment: The line where you say `setContentView(DakotasLayout);`. Because you are only setting your layout to a `RelativeLayout` and the button you add to it your `findViewById(...)` methods are returning null and crashing your application. You need to update that line to reference a layout file that actually has in it the views you are looking up.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Get ride of setContentView(DakotasLayout);?

Comment: This looks like an automatically generated activity. Look inside the res/layout directory of your project. There you should hopefully see a layout xml file. Then your method should look like `setContentView(R.layout.layout_file_name)`.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan I have activity_main.xml. I set it like this :setContentView(R.layout.activity_main.xml);

Comment: Yes except without the `.xml` extension. You should be able to let auto complete do its job for you. `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: See again my comment. I said remove the `.xml` and even gave what the line should be. `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: @George Mulligan It works dude. You're the man.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Any other views you want to add to your layout should go inside that xml file. You then get a reference to them in your `Activity` using the `findViewById(...)` method.

Comment: That is just template code to get you started. If you don't need it you can remove it. If you don't want an action bar remove the toolbar from your layout file and the MainActivity class.

Comment: Try removing all other methods except `onCreate()`. In that method just have `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not setting a valid layout for what your activity is expecting. Your layout needs to have in it a defined view for each call to `findViewById(...);` you have. The view's ID will match what you pass into the method.

Currently you are only setting your content view to a relative layout with a button so you are likely getting a `NullPointerException` when you lookup other views using `findViewById(...);` and later try to use them.

Look inside your `res/layout` directory for a valid layout file and use that as your content view instead since this looks like a template to begin with.

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`